# Python pool and append / update a global dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. I am trying to bring in large chunks of data through pd.read_csv. Records can be +400 million records.I am using pools and chunking the data inorder to stop myself from running out of memory. I initially wanted all the data in a dataframe to do grouping but my memory is not holding up. 
So I wanted to use a groupby function on the chunks ,append it to a local dictionary then append it to a global dictionary. The global dictionary will contain an incremental count of the local dictionary and will not be lost due to the chunk and pool size defined...Can anyone help ??

## the function being called from main

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
groupby = df.groupby(['type'])['type'].count()

#local dictionary
type_dict_temp['type']=groupby
for typevalue in df['type']:
    if typevalue in type_dict.keys():
        type_dict[typevalue] += 1
    else:
        type_dict[typevalue]

return df


    pool = mp.Pool(processes= mp.cpu_count())
    reader = pd.read_csv(LARGE_FILE,sep=',',chunksize=chunksize, error_bad_lines=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, lineterminator='\n')
    ##initializing the dictionary
    manager = Manager()
    type_dict=manager.dict()
    type_dict_temp=manager.dict()

    for df in reader:
        f=pool.apply_async(process_frame,[df])

    main()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    pool.terminate()

    for (k, v) in type_dict.items():
        print(k,":", v)
```